# server status configuration in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-status

I have recently replaced my apache web server with nginx

I want to know how can I write below statements for nginx server status

```
<Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 10.
        Allow from 127.
    </Location>
```

Comment: You could use http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html which is the equivalent built-in service of nginx.

Comment: yes , i tried this
locations:
      '/nginx_status/':
        stub_status: 'on'
        access_log:   'off'
        deny: 'all'
        allow: '127.'
        allow: '10.'
But it gives error for writing "10." , how can I write like this for nginx. It worked for apache but not nginx

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html nginx config is pretty different from Apache so I can only advise to spend some time reading its documentation.